# JavaScript Error: Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason JavaScript doesn't seem to recognise my function.

I have a button in some HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="lightOn" onclick="lightOn()">On</button>
```

and then a bit of JavaScript:

```
function lightOn(){
    $("#lightOn").addClass("active");
    $("#lightOff").removeClass("active");
    socket.emit("setting", {"light":"on"});
}
```

When I click on the button I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: lightOn is not a function

Any idea why this won't work?

Thanks.

Comment: `lightOn` must be in the head of your document in this instance https://jsfiddle.net/2362mjox/

Comment: Is your js properly loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you give to your element the same id : `"lightOn"`. In this scope `lightOn` is the element, which shadows the function ([read more](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html)).

A simple solution would be to give a different id to the element or a different name to the function.

A better one would be to separate the script from the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="lightOn">On</button>

$(function(){
    $('#lightOn').click(function() {
        $("#lightOn").addClass("active");
        $("#lightOff").removeClass("active");
        socket.emit("setting", {"light":"on"});
    });
});
```

Comment: correct answer. There are better ways of setting this interaction up, but this is why the op's code is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `onclick` attribute, it is much cleaner to add the event listener in JavaScript, like so:

```js
$('#lightOn').on('click', function() {
  $("#lightOn").addClass("active");
  $("#lightOff").removeClass("active");
  socket.emit("setting", {"light":"on"});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="lightOn">On</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var lightOn = function(){

}
```

And you can do all of this in vanilla JS instead of using jQuery too:

```
var lightOn = function(){
    document.getElementById('lightOn').className += " active";
    document.getElementById('lightOff').className.replace(/\bactive\b/,'');
    socket.emit("setting", {"light":"on"});
}
```

A good explanation for `var lightOn = function()` and `function lightOn()` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/1887101